# Numbers in kotlin is not serializable

Tags: spring, serialization, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I found that numbers in kotlin is not serializable.

1. First problem

Device.kt:

```
package test.domain

import javax.persistence.*

Entity public class Device {
    public Id GeneratedValue var id: Long = -1
    public var name: String = ""
    ...
}
```

DeviceRestRepository.kt:

```
package test.domain

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource

RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "device", path = "device")
public trait DeviceRestRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Device, Long?> {
    public fun findByName(Param("name") name: String): List<Device>
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile this code, because **kotlin.Long** is not **Serializable**:

> Error:(14, 72) Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should
>   be subtype of 'java.io.Serializable?'

2. Second problem

I get the same error when I try to use **java.lang.Long**:

DeviceRestRepository.kt:

```
package test.domain

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource

RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "device", path = "device")
public trait DeviceRestRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Device, java.lang.Long?> {
    public fun findByName(Param("name") name: String): List<Device>
}
```

> Warning:(14, 72) Kotlin: This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use
>   kotlin.Long instead.
>
> Error:(14, 72) Kotlin: Type argument is not
>   within its bounds: should be subtype of 'java.io.Serializable?'

Comment: Although your workaround is good enough (and congratulations on finding it!), this is a problem in the Kotlin infrastructure, and we'll do our best to fix it.

Please watch this issue to get notify about our progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5821

Comment: AndreyPaslavsky thanks for the workaround,
@AndreyBreslav, glad to hear that this will be solved. 
And if you can please clarify why is java.lang.Long not Serializable from Kotlin perspective while it is Serializable in Java? Thanks.

Comment: @beegor, `java.lang.Long` is not serializable because Kotlin sees it as a subclass of `kotlin.Number` (not `java.lang.Number`), which is not serializable. This mapping `j.l.Number -> k.Number` is necessary to make Kotlin/Java interop work smoothly, when Kotlin calls Java methods

Comment: Hmm, while this solution works for reading from database, inserting new  record is not working as it should, ID is always -1 instead being generated by DB (postgresql). Am I missing something here?

Comment: See my new answer below, this is no longer an issue.  Can you review and confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As-of Kotlin 1.0 Beta 1 primitive types are serializable:

> Int is Serializable
>
> Now the type Int and other basic types are Serializable on the JVM. This should help many frameworks.

from:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out/

Therefore you no longer have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround of this problem:

Device.kt:

```
package test.domain

import javax.persistence.*

Entity public class Device {
    public EmbeddedId var id: DeviceId = DeviceId()
    public var name: String = ""
    ...
}

Embeddable public class DeviceId: Serializable {
    public GeneratedValue var id: Long = -1
}
```

DeviceRestRepository.kt:

```
package test.domain

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource

RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "device", path = "device")
public trait DeviceRestRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Device, DeviceId?> {
    public fun findByName(Param("name") name: String): List<Device>
}
```

This use-case works fine

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue and I managed to deal with it by having my Repository interfaces in java, where I gave **java.lang.Long** as the generic type argument for the id. The rest remained in kotlin(data classes, service classes, etc.)